# go race detector can't run because of import error. ports runtime/race: cannot find package "runtime/race" in any of GOROOT or GOPATH

Tags: go, gccgo

my os is ubuntu18.04. 
my go compiler is gccgo.
GOROOT is /usr/local/go
it is report as:
package testmain
    imports runtime/race: cannot find package "runtime/race" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/race (from $GOROOT)
    /home/lzx/tiny_distributed_system/src/runtime/race (from $GOPATH)

Comment: Show us tree. of your working directory.

Comment: `gccgo` doesn’t support the race detector.

Comment: So how to change gccgo , I just use initial golang @JimB

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Just install Go normally: https://golang.org/doc/install

Comment: thank you. Maybe i initially install go with gccgo.Now it works